# How to clear all Textboxes and ComboBoxes in all UserControls?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am currently writing a program that when a button is clicked on a final `UserControl`it clears all the `TextBox` and `ComboBox` in all `UserControls` within the program.

I have created a method within my `OverviewControl` that I am trying to call on a button that would clear all the Textbox's and ComboBox's within the `GeneralControl` and `StatsControl` classes.

**MainForm.cs**

```
public MainForm() 
{
   overviewControl1.GeneralControl = generalControl1;
   overviewControl1.StatsControl = statsControl1;
}
```

**OverviewControl.cs**

```
public partial class OverviewControl : UserControl
{
      public GeneralControl GeneralControl { get; set; }
      public StatsControl StatsControl { get; set; }

      private void GeneralSaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          ClearItems();
      }

      private void ClearItems()
      {
          foreach (Control c in GeneralControl?.Controls)
          {
              if (c is TextBox tb)
                  tb.Clear();
              else if (c is ComboBox cb)
                  cb.SelectedIndex = -1;
          }

          foreach (Control c in StatsControl?.Controls)
          {
              if (c is TextBox tb)
                  tb.Clear();
              else if (c is ComboBox cb)
                  cb.SelectedIndex = -1;
          }
     }
}
```

I am expecting that when I click my button, it calls the `GeneralSaveButton_Click()` method and it clears all fields from the `GeneralControl` and `StatsControl` but all fields remain there after calling the method.
Any help getting pointed in the right direction would be helpful.

Comment: have you tried using the debugger to ensure it finds your controls etc

Comment: This: `foreach (Control c in GeneralControl?.Controls)` returns all Controls that are direct children of the UserControl. If a Control is inside another container, it won't be part of that collection. If this is the case, you need a simple recursion.

Comment: The `TextBox` and `ComboBox` that I would like to clear are in a `TableLayoutPanel` would that be why it is not working correctly?

Comment: Yes, of course. If all of your controls are inside TableLayoutPanels, use the TLP collection of controls instead. You could write something like: `foreach (var tlp in GeneralControl.Controls.OfType<TableLayoutPanel>().ToList())
foreach(Control c in tlp.Controls) { if (c is TextBox tb) { tb.Clear(); } }` etc.

Comment: After some clever `ToString()` I was able to find out where the areas were located to clear them, Thank you so much!